# Joining multiple tables to produce one data source

Tags: sql

I have four tables with similar format but different values.

Table A

| ID | Date     | Photo
| 14 | 10/10/24 |   1
| 15 | 10/11/24 |   2
| 16 | 10/12/24 |   1
| 17 | 10/13/24 |   1

Table B

| ID | Date     | Photo
| 14 | 10/10/24 |   1
| 15 | 10/11/24 |   1
| 17 | 10/16/24 |   1
| 18 | 10/17/24 |   1

Table C
| ID | Date     | Photo
| 14 | 10/10/24 |   1
| 15 | 10/11/24 |   4
| 19 | 10/18/24 |   4
| 20 | 10/19/24 |   1

I need to get one data source that looks like this below, that is a full outer join of the above tables, where the ID and Date fields as the only fields with non values.

Table C

| ID | Date           | Photo | Image | Cat

| 14 | 10/10/2014     | 1     |   1   | 1

| 15 | 10/11/2014     | 2     |   1   | 4

| 16 | 10/12/2014      | 1 | NULL | NULL

| 17 | 10/16/2014     | NULL | 1 | NULL

| 18 | 10/14/2014     | NULL | NULL | NULL

| 18 | 10/17/2014     | NULL | 1 | NULL

| 19 | 10/15/2014     | NULL | NULL | 4

| 20 | 10/16/2014     | 1 | NULL | NULL

| 20 | 10/19/2014      | NULL | NULL | 1

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Share your attempt please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE` or `NVL` to ensure that the `ID` and `Date` columns are not null.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.ID, b.ID,c.ID) AS ID,
        COALESCE(a."Date", b."Date", c."Date") AS "Date",
        a.Photo,
        b.Image,
        c.Cat
FROM    TableA a
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        TableB b
        ON ( a.ID = b.ID )
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        TableC c
        ON ( c.ID = COALESCE( a.ID, b.ID ) );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29de8/2)

Answer (score 0):

You mention `FULL JOIN` so I'm assuming you use a database that supports them.  You can use `COALESCE()` to return the populated `ID` and `Date`, and also to simplify your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID,c.ID) AS ID
      ,COALESCE(a.Date,b.Date,c.Date) AS Date 
      ,a.Photo
      ,b.Image
      ,c.Cat
FROM TableA a
FULL JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ID = b.ID  AND a.Date = b.Date
FULL JOIN TableC c
  ON COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID) = c.ID  AND COALESCE(a.Date,b.Date) = c.Date
```

Comment: Thanks that works. What would happen if I were joining more than three tables. Can I use the same logic and increment my coalesce statements

Comment: @VijayKumar Exactly, `TableD` would have `COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID,c.ID) = d.ID`, etc.